# ElasticSearch geolocation and performance

Tags: geolocation, elasticsearch, geohashing

I was wondering:
what's best for indexing places' geolocation ? Geohash or lon/lat ?

I search places based on the distance between the user and the place so what's best for ElasticSearch ? I think Geohash is more powerful but I may be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Geohash is just a form of lon/lat representation with different accuracy. You should specify geo-point type in your mapping:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-point-type.html, and you could use both geohash or lon/lot form.